# Inner loop not printing column of a single line matrix Java intellij

Tags: java

I just began learning Java on intellij and I'm following an Edx course which no one responds to questions in the discussion board. The nested loops codes in the lesson aren't printing outa 5x5 matrix of zeros like it says it should with a space between the zeros. Should the last println statement be aligned with the outer for loop? If so, why won't intellij let me align? I get a single column of 5 zeros printed 5 times instead. Copied code directly also and same problem.

```
public class NestedLoop2 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    for (int row = 1; row <= 5; row++) {
        for (int col = 1; col <= 5; col++) {
            System.out.println("0 ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("0 ");
                ^^
```

The `println` prints a newline each time. You want

```
System.out.print("0 ");
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know there was just a print() statement yet. So many errors on Edx java microsoft course, I'm tired of bringing up and no one answers. I see why only small number take this course.

Comment: Welcome to the world of online courses.  Many are of extremely low quality, "you get what you pay for" applies, but even paying for something online is no guarantee :-)  Your best bet is the language reference guide (dry reading but accurate and complete) and a good tutorial.  Try starting with Oracle's official Java tutorial instead.

Comment: Will do. Thanks.